Installing Lubuntu on Trekstor Windows PC
My Trekstor Surftab twin 11.6 has a problem, it can't boot from the USB where there's the installer of Lubuntu (I used Rufus) but even if I remove secure boot the PC Will flash and go back in the BIOS. How do I fix this?
Here's the link where you can see the video: click here
Thanks :)

Welcome. Don't waste your time. Your device is de facto obsolete, never had good support for Linux and never will. Avoid anything from the "Bay Trail" family of CPUs and almost all from the "Cherry Tail" family like yours. That said, a properly made live/installation media should boot so that's your problem, not the hardware itself. The problems with hardware will come later if you manage to boot and install any Linux, most things won't work.

The same problem arrives if I try to install any OS, I tried now with Windows 8.1 but there's the same problem

So, either you're doing something when preparing the media, the media itself has issues (try a different one) or the tablet has some other unknown problem. And you shouldn't install any out of support OS like Win8.1 anyway. It supports Win10 that can be used for one more year. Win11 is out of the question, reason why it's de facto obsolete. Again, you're wasting your time.
